# The requested URL was not found on this server - Angular 2 Routing with Google Cloud

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

The issue that I am currently experiencing is when I attempt to put in a specific route for example: "www.example.com/projects".  This then produces:

> Error: Not Found
>   The requested URL /projects was not found on this server.

**Note:** This does not happen when navigating to that route via UI, it only happens when refreshing the page or typing in the specific url. 
One thing to mention is the I am using the google cloud platform and I set up the application first using angular cli.  
I have seen multiple things stating that I have to serve the index.html for each route however I cannot find any documentation as to how to do that or even if that is the correct way to go about it.  
I am not sure what all you would need to help me figure this out so I will update with what you need to assist.

I got the Hash Location Strategy working, but I am trying to get the Path Location Strategy working.

Thank you for all help!

Comment: Try using  Hash Location Strategy in angularjs2

Comment: I have explored the Hash Location Strategy option and I got that working however I would like to explore the Path Location Strategy to try getting that working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your app.yaml file, update your handler's regular expression to look like this:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

The dist file is the static output from cli. Add any file extensions in the first handler if your app uses more.

Hope it works

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly!  I had something similar at one point but it never worked, must have had something messed up with it.

Answer (score 2):

I have made use of HashLocationStrategy available in Angular for this. I am unable to use PathLocationStrategy in my angular application when deploying it on Google cloud instance. If I use PathLocationStrategy, then I get the error:

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /projects was not found on this server.

For achieving HashLocationStrategy I simply used two lines of code in my app.module.ts

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
})

export class AppModule
```

After all this I have realized it is better to use default path strategy that is available with angular, i.e., PathLocationStrategy. As told by Nicholas in the above answer, I am unable to find app.yaml file in my project structure which I created using angular-cli v1.4

It would be great if someone could guide me in a right direction here.

Comment: `find . -type f -name "app.yaml"`. That command will locate any missing `app.yaml` files if they exist. However I don't think the angular CLI creates an `app.yaml` - that's purely a construct of google app engine.

Answer (score 1):

add useHash:true in the router module it should works for angular 5 and java 
like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})
],
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Your server side application should only render the base route `"/"` So that your Single page application can handle the routing to `/projects`.

2- You may also overcome this issue by adding hash `#` prefix to your client side routing like `"www.example.com/#/projects"`

In AngularJs you would do this by adding below code to your `config` function

```
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(false);
```

Comment: Which file would be the config file where I would put this?  I am trying to find an app.js file but it seems Angular 2 CLI does it differently?

Also is there any way to do it without having the '#' showing?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using PathLocationStrategy (html5 history) you need to have a handler to catch those dynamic routes

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
# index files
- url: /([^.]+)/?$  # urls with no dot in them
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

# everything else
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element