# Route not working what is wrong in my code

Tags: angular, routes

I have this route in my app-routing.module.ts that missing something because
when I go to this page

> https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com/search

I get error but when I go here it works

> https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SearchBooksComponent } from './search-books/search-books.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/search',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchBooksComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

What is wrong with the route?

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
```

Comment: Your server configuration. [RTFM](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

Comment: also make sure `redirectTo: 'search',`

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Yea but i´m a newbie did not know about manuals :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested URL was not found on this server - Angular 2 Routing with Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770151/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-angular-2-routing-with-google-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect to `search` instead of `/search`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'search',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchBooksComponent
  }
];
```

The routes order matters only when two routes conflict, as in `search` and `**`. The `search` will be matched by both routes, and first one wins.

You can use hash location strategy like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770151/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-angular-2-routing-with-google-c/41842773#answer-50139814).
Path Location strategy is also explained in this question.

Comment: Trying this and get "Error: Not Found The requested URL / search was not found on this server:" . Removing "/search" like this works ok - [https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com](https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com)

Comment: @Erik could you update your question with your `app.yaml`?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770151/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-angular-2-routing-with-google-c/41842773

Comment: Thanks from that Q @asli answer I did like this  `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})` and it seams to work

Answer (score 0):

The order in which we set routes is crucial. try this!.
set default route at last.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchBooksComponent } from './search-books/search-books.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'search', component: SearchBooksComponent },
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'search',pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Strange this works on LocalHost but not at GCP, try the link
[https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com/search](https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com/search) should redirect but not. removing /search and it works

Comment: @Erik the routes order does not matter in this case, check my answer. The important think is `search` instead of `/search`.

Comment: Really I get after deploy to GCP : Error: Not Found
The requested URL / search was not found on this server.